# How do you get the first part of a URI in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, url, path, uri, string-parsing

I have a button on my navbar. When clicked, I want a different behavior depending on which URI the user is currently on.

Let's say that I have this URI `localhost:8080/entity/{entityId}`
How can I get `entity`, the first part of the URI, as a string in Angular 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the answer from Angular's doc, you have to use the UrlSegment Angular class from `@angular/router` to parse the url in segments
link to the relevant doc: https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSegment

```
const tree: UrlTree = router.parseUrl('/team;id=33');
const g: UrlSegmentGroup = tree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
const s: UrlSegment[] = g.segments;
s[0].path; // returns 'team'
s[0].parameters; // returns {id: 33}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must to import ActivatedRoute from Angular =>

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

Next Inject activatedRoute in your Component constructor =>

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

Now you can access to your children's routes, this console log will output an array of childrens.

```
ngOnInit() {
 console.log(this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.children);
}
```

You can get a lot of info about your url with ActivatedRoute.
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 0):

You can split the current url on the basis of '/', it will convert the url into an array and you can get any part you want.
See the code snippet below:

```
url =window.location.href;

console.log(this.url.split('/')[1]);
```